# Google Analytics: Report on users based on the presence of a specific cookie

Tags: php, google-analytics

Is it possible to report on users based on the presence of a specific cookie?

In particular reporting on ecommerce sales with visitors who had a specific cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use use user defined variables to filter visits from a webprofile

to do this set a user defined value
_gaq.push(['_setVar', 'SOME_VALUE']);

This will set a cookie on the users browser with SOME_VALUE

Next create a filter in the analytics profile to either include or exclude visitors with this cookie value.

Go to Filters > New Filter > Select Custom Filter > Check either exlcude or include
Filter Field User Defined
Filter Pattern SOME_VALUE

Case sensitive No
Hit Save.

Now all the data in the profile including ecommerce data will be filtered based on this cookie.

If you dont want to filter at profile level you can also use visitor level custom varaibles  and then create advanced segment to see certain value of variable at a time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would not have thought this is possible, as that information would need to also be passed to GA at the time of logging.

You would need to use that cookie to append something, like a campaign source to the next URL clicked in order to get that logged.

Event tracking  may also be a way to go.

Comment: Would custom variables allow visitors to be segment?  If so would i place a visitor level push only once on the site: directly after order has been placed.  or does it need to go on every page

Comment: yes I think this possible. Looking at tracking events for example, you can create a custom segment on 'visits with event'. So you add code to detect the cookie and fire an event if found, and your custom segment should show give you what you're looking for. More on Custom Segments here: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033017